# Using a string column value with concatenated ids as a foreign key in JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

One of the columns of my database is a string with denormalized ids like `"3,7,8"`. I cannot change that legacy logic of the db.

I am currently using a `@Converter` to convert the field to a `List<Integer>`, but I'd like to do a second pass so the entity directly defines:

```
@Column
@OneToMany
List<ForeignEntity>
```

Is there any native way to tell JPA to make a second pass to convert it?

I know I could resolve in the converter, but I am looking a neater way, to save me from using queries inside the data converter, and take profit of the standard JPA annotations and mechanisms.

Indeed, my foreign entity is nothing else than a map, if somebody could point me to a better solution so I could do it even more complex and resolve directly

```
id | key | value
----------------
3  | A   |  ...
3  | B   |  ...
3  | C   |  ...
7  | A   |  ...
7  | B   |  ...
7  | C   |  ...
...
```

into

```
@Column
@OneToMany
List<Map<String,String>> resolvedValues; // Contains {Map[A,B,C]{... , ..., ...}, Map[A,B,C]{... , ..., ...}, ... }
```

I'd be really greateful!

Answer (score 0):

You could use - `javax.persistence.AttributeConverter` interface of JPA.

By overriding its method :

```
@Override
 public String convertToDatabaseColumn(ForeignEntity fe) {
.
.
.
}
```

Here is the specs -

> https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/AttributeConverter.html

Comment: Thanks! but I am already using it. As I said, I am currently converting the string into a List<Integers>. The thing is how to use usual JPA annotations to decode it as my referenced entity, in order to save me from subquerying in the converter code